# Website button not working in iphon's safari browser

Tags: vue.js, button, browser, safari, mobile-website

I have developed a website in javascript Vue js, I am not able to click the button in the iPhone safari browser, but it runs fine in iPad, chrome, android phone's chrome browser.

Comment: any error message ?.

Comment: no how can i inspect there? it just runs everywhere except iPhone safari.